# Why does this code keep looping?

Tags: vba

We are stuck in a loop and cannot get it to continue to pull values. This code will just pull the first value and keep looping.

```
Sub createpbp()

    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer 'webtext row counter
    Dim iR As Integer
    Dim iPr As Integer 'row counter for pbp worksheet
    Dim wksWT As Worksheet


    iPr = 1

    Set wksWT = Worksheets("Webtext") 'creating a variable for the text pulled from website

    wksWT.Activate 'activate the webtext sheet

    iRows = wksWT.UsedRange.rows.Count 'counts rows in the play by play

    For i = 1 To iRows 'row 1 to end of rows
        If Cells(i, 1) = "Play By Play Innings" Then 'if the cell value says play by play innings
            Do Until Cells(i, 1) = "Runs" 'continue doing the following until reach end of inning
                Cells(i, 1).Copy 'copy the value of the first event in inning
                Sheets("Play by Play text").Select 'open up new worksheet
                If Cells(iPr, 1) = Null Then
                    Cells(iPr, 1).Paste
                Else
                    iPr = iPr + 1
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Look at Do Until Cells(i, 1) = "Runs"... if Cells(i,1) <> "Runs", this loop will run forever since nothing in this loop is modifying i

Answer (score 1):

Something isn't right about your loop.

```
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = "Runs"
```

I don't see anywhere in your loop that changes the value of this cell to "Runs".  And I don't see anywhere in your loop that increments the value of `i`.